# Writing Loop Script for GRASS

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am new to Python and scripting in general.

My overall goal is to create a script that I can cycle through all the raster maps in a mapset and then save the univariate stats to a .csv file for each raster map.  I am working on the first part: cycling through all the maps and printing the stats to the terminal window. Later, I will try and save the data to a .csv file.  I have seven maps in my practice mapset and I get seven errors, but my problem is that I do not know what variable to assign to the parameter MAP (hopefully, I stated that correctly).

Here is what I have thus far:

```
import sys
import os
import grass.script as grass
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
gisdb="/Users/kc/GrassData"
location="Data_2013"
mapset="methods_check"
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)
grass.run_command("g.list", _type="rast") 
mymaps = grass.parse_command("g.list", _type="rast") 
print len(mymaps) 
for items in mymaps:
    grass.run_command('r.univar', map='items', separator=",")
```

What should I put for map = 'items' so that it cycles through all the raster maps of a mapset?

I am using GRASS 7.0, but the same thing happens in GRASS 6.5.  In Grass 6.5, the parameter separator must be changed to fs. Both versions label the input file "map".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between:

- **grass.run_command** which performs a GRASS command

```py
grass.run_command('g.remove', raster="raster1")
```

- **grass.read_command** which is used to receive a result (generally a string, same result as the command in GRASS GIS, of little interest to Python, you need to use the [re (Regular Expression)](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) module to process the result)

```py
grass.read_command("g.region",flags="p")  
'projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)\nzone:       0\ndatum:      bel72\nellipsoid:  international\nnorth:      112990.07863053\nsouth:      108258.30027318\nwest:       227552.40388837\neast:       235027.97855494\nnsres:      6.35138035\newres:      6.35138035\nrows:       745\ncols:       1177\ncells:      876865\n'
```

- **grass.parse_command** that parse the result for Python (generally a dictionary)

```py
grass.parse_command("g.region",flags="p")  
{'ellipsoid:  international': None, 'zone:       0': None, 'nsres:      6.35138035': None, 'south:      108258.30027318': None, 'ewres:      6.35138035': None, 'west:       227552.40388837': None, 'rows:       745': None, 'east:       235027.97855494': None, 'projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)': None, 'cells:      876865': None, 'north:      112990.07863053': None, 'cols:       1177': None, 'datum:      bel72': None}
```

So, in your case, it is not:

```
grass.run_command("g.list", _type="rast")
```

whose result is 0

but:

```
rasters = grass.read_command("g.list",_type="rast")
```

whose result is a string with all the layers in the variable rasters

```
type(raster)
<type 'str'>
```

But it is not interesting at all here, because you only need the names of the layers:

```
rasters = grass.parse_command("g.list", _type="rast")
```

whose result is a Python dictionary and for further, see [Python Scripts For GRASS GIS: Using "parse_command()"](http://code.google.com/p/postgis-grass-r-py/wiki/0003_01_PythonForGrassGis#Using_%22parse_command%28%29%22)

The result is a list with the layer names:

```
['raster1', 'raster2', 'raster3']
```

so the processing is:

```
for items in mymaps:
     grass.parse_command('r.univar', map=items)
```

.

Comment: Thank you. I am still carefully working through your valuable comments (I am new to this.). If I understand correctly, my primary issue is that I need to parse the dictionary that holds my maps. I need more time to work on it.